# Why can't I use "List" as class name of a subclass of UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

Why can't I use "List" as class name of a subclass of UITableViewController?

Comment: Because `List` is much too vague and not a good class name ;-) See Graham Lee's answer for the true reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there's a `List` class already. You shouldn't use it (in fact I'm not sure you can on the iPhone because its interface requires `@defs` to work), but it's there. It's an old class, inheriting from `Object`, that provides a mutable array of configurable capacity.

Comment: Cool. Real answer from heavy experience. I'll report this to Apple's bug reporter.